# Libgdx game, why doesn't this table display?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Ok so I'm developing an android/desktop game with libgdx.  I've made a lot of progress lately but one issue remains.

I have an if/else block that checks if the user has a name stored in shared preferences.  If there isn't one, a libgdx window pops up with a text input and a button.  Once the button is clicked to submit, the players information is sent to the server, the server sends back a list of high scores, and a table is built to display them.  The problem is, I don't see my table at this point.  The debug lines are draw and I am 100% certain the data comes back clean as I can print it all out.

However, if the user does have a name in shared preferences and the if/else block skips down to else without the input window popping up, the same exact buildHighScores() function works perfectly.

I realize it is stupid to do all this work in a click listener but I have tried moving things all around and executing in different orders with no success. I also know the whole thing could be structured better but I'm not sure why this doesn't work.  Thanks.

...initialize everything....

```
    // click listener for input window button
    btnSubmitName.addListener(new ClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void clicked(
                com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent event, float x,
                float y) {
            super.clicked(event, x, y);
            stage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeOut(1), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // check database if name is taken
                        if(netcode.IsNameTaken(txtVal) == false) {
                            prefs.putString("name", txtVal);
                            prefs.flush();
                            System.out.println("thnx " + txtVal + " m8");

                            /////////////////////////////////////////
                            // doesn't display table, only debug lines
                            /////////////////////////////////////////
                            buildHighScores();

                            inputOK = true;
                        }
                        else System.out.println("name is taken");
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            })));
        }
    });

    if(prefs.getString("name", null) == null)
    {
        System.out.println("ok...");
        try {
            netcode.setState(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Adding Input Window...");

        stage.addActor(window);

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Name not null...");

        //////////////////////////
        // displays table perfectly
        //////////////////////////
        buildHighScores();  
    }
```

...stage.act & stage.draw...

```
    public void buildHighScores() {
    playerdata.setPlayerName(prefs.getString("name"));
    System.out.println("hey " + playerdata.getPlayerName());

    highScoreString = prefs.getString("highscore");
    String decodedString = Base64Coder.decodeString(highScoreString);
    System.out.println(decodedString);
    playerdata.setHighScore(Integer.parseInt(decodedString));

    try {
        netcode.setState(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // connect to server and update play
    try {
        netcode.serverConnect(playerdata);
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        System.out.println("socket exception brah");
        //gsm.setState(0);
        e.printStackTrace();
        //stage.addActor(errorWindow);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // get high score list from server
    HighScoreList = netcode.GetHighScores();

    // not necessary
    for(int i = 0 ; i < HighScoreList.size() ; i++) {
        String tmp = new String(i+1 + " " + HighScoreList.get(i).getPlayerName() + " " + HighScoreList.get(i).getHighScore());
        HighScoresList.add(tmp);
        //System.out.println(tmp);
    }

    // build scoresTable with the high score list we got from server
    scoresTable.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0 ; i < HighScoresList.size() ; i++){
        scoresTable.add(new Label(""+(i+1), labelStyle)).left();
        scoresTable.add().width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6);
        scoresTable.add(new Label(HighScoreList.get(i).getPlayerName(), labelStyle)).left();
        scoresTable.add().width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6);
        scoresTable.add(new Label(""+HighScoreList.get(i).getHighScore(), labelStyle)).left();
        scoresTable.row();
        //System.out.println(i);
    }
    scoresTable.debug();

    // add scoresTable to a scrollpane
    scrollpane = new ScrollPane(scoresTable);

    // create table to display high scores
    table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    table.add(label);
    table.row();
    table.add(textfield).width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2);
    table.row();
    table.add(scrollpane).fill().height(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
    table.row();
    table.add(button2);
    table.debug();

    stage.clear();
    stage.addActor(table);
}
```

Comment: in the if condition you need to reset the current frame/activity.. for the saved changes to take effect

Comment: Is the Preferences instance you use a singleton? (Are you making sure that there is only one instance of it) because I ran into the mistake of creating multiple copies and then flushing did not work at all. Also, are you certain that the table is initialized as intended? (I have not used the table, I made my own list view but it was not a table)